# Attempting to use xvkbd and xbindkeys to cycle trough apps

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

When pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and holding <kbd>Tab</kbd>, one can cycle trough applications in Ubuntu. If you press these two buttons and release them right away then you move to the last application that you were using. My goal is to press a button in my mouse which does this action.

I have achieved this using the following file `~/.xbindkeysrc` which contains the following:

```
"xvkbd -text '\A\t'"
b:9
```

This works many times, but sometimes only the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is pressed or the action is repeated many times, with unwanted consequences. I have tried adding the `-no-repeat` flag, which didn't solve the problem either.

Thank you.

Comment: I would also really like to do this, but unfortunately it never works for me. Did you try `b:9 + release`?

Comment: Thanks, it works pretty well now! However, I need to do '\A\t\C'" instead of  '\A\t'".